# Confused to Serializer relations in Django Rest

Tags: django-rest-framework

In the Serializer relations part on Django official website, it provides a music albums example to represent and explain some relationship.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks')
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('album', 'order')
        ordering = ['order']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%d: %s' % (self.order, self.title)
```

Later, it interacts model with Serializer.

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

The result is:

```
{
    'album_name': 'Things We Lost In The Fire',
    'artist': 'Low',
    'tracks': [
        '1: Sunflower',
        '2: Whitetail',
        '3: Dinosaur Act',
        ...
    ]
}
```

I am confused variable tracks in the AlbumSerializer. It seems that the variable tracks is irrelevant to Album and Track model.How it is related to the Album and Track models? How it calls and invokes **unicode**  method of Track model in the AlbumSerializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related via `related_name`

```
album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks')
```

The related_name attribute specifies the name of the reverse relation from Album to Track.

Read more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: @ Arun Ghosh Is variable tracks in related_name same as the variable tracks in AlbumSerializer?

Comment: @pipi both refer to same.